# LIS3DH- Understanding Z axis output

Tags: noise, accelerometer

I am trying to measure a machine's vibration using LIS3DH sensor. 
I set the LIS3DH in low power mode and 5.376 kHz sampling frequency which outputs 8 bit output. I use SPI to get the data from the sensor. I changed this raw output into ’g' using the sensitivity value given in the datasheet.
My problem is: The sensor shows a fluctuation in its output of Z axis even when there is no vibration applied and the sensor is fitted on a horizontal surface. The range of this fluctuation is approximately from 0.6g to 1.2g. I have attached a image that shows such output. (X axis is time and Y axis is vibration in terms of g)
 [image]
Can someone please help me to interpret why this is happening ? Is there a method to somehow remove this noise from the output ?

Answer (score 1):

The Z axis should show about 1m/s<sup>2</sup>  when level because it is measuring the force of gravity. The noise could be vibration due to nearby fans, machinery, wind, even people walking in the area. It will pickup very subtle vibrations.

To reduce the noise, if you do not need high sensitivity, reduce the scale of the LIS3DH. Alternatively, you could handle this is in software through averaging, moving averages, etc. You could also consider implementing a software low pass filter.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  I don't think the source of the noise is vibration.  You can prove this as follows: the LIS3DH has an internal temperature sensor.  Measure the temperature using this sensor.  If your results are the same as mine, you will find that the temperature jumps around within a range of 2 degrees C.  This is obviously not what the temperature is  actually doing, so it must be noise.  I don't know the source of the noise.  If you find out what is the source, pleas Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to address this issue:  I wrote some code that takes 20 measurements and averages them.  The code submits that average back to the calling routine instead of the raw data.  This reduces the noise amplitude by about a factor of 10x.  Not very elegant, but it works.